# Numbered list changes to reflect visible elements

Tags: jquery, count, numbers

I have a list of item that I need to be numbered. Once the user clicks a button one of the numbered list items displays none. I then need the numbered list to change to reflect the new order.

I am able to return the number of list item and that this may be a way of changing the numbers in the list.

```
var btn = $('.btn');
var hide = $('.hide');
var shm = $('.showHowMany');

$(btn).click(function(){
   $(hide).css({"display": "none"});
   $(function () {   
    var howMany=$('p:visible').length;
        if(howMany === 2){$(shm).html('There are ' + howMany); }
    });
});
```

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of how this might be achieved.

[Jfiddle of what I have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/rkdfbpzt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the removal of a `p`, you can use the `text()` function to loop over each of the remaining elements. You can then split the text by spaces, remove the first item, append the index of that element and rejoin it all back together. Try this:

```
$('.wrapper p:visible').text(function(i, v) {
    var words = v.split(' ');
    words.shift();
    return (i + 1) + ' ' + words.join(' ');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rkdfbpzt/3/)

Also note that I tidied your code a little, as you were double-wrapping your jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks Rory, that's exactly what I was after.